# Errors in Eclipse after Java update

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently updated java, I went to eclipse opened up my code and saw that there were a lot of errors that weren't there before I saved last time I dont know what it's asking for and I know its not a problem with my code. Everytime i run it says the following:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: String
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

as well as saying an JNI error has occured as well as Java Exception.

I haven't tried adding classes as I don't know what will happen if I do.

Comment: I guess you're using  the newest Eclipse version?

Comment: yes the newest version

Comment: Ok. I asked because older eclipse versions have problems with Java 8, but this wasn't the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remove the old version when you upgraded Java? Go to Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and check that the new version is selected.

If the new version isn't listed, use the Search button.

Comment: I opened it up again and it was fixed I checked your steps anyways it had already been done thank you anyways